# Run intellij application with sudo privileges

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a scala application that needs to perform `sys.process` operations with `sudo` and these operations are failing for me. From my google searching, it appears that I may be able to resolve this by running intellij with `sudo`. However, when I do this, I'm prompted to import settings and need would need to re-import my project. This seems less than ideal. Is there a way to set up a run configuration in intellij to have `sudo` privileges or at least run `idea.sh` with `sudo` but use my original workspace, so that all changes and configurations are shared between the `sudo` and non-`sudo` profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is down to Intellij reading its settings from a directory under the current user directory, eg C:\Users\matt.IntelliJIdea13 on my Windows PC. When you sudo, it will try and read its setting from a different directory.

I would check with directory it is trying to save its config to when you run it with sudo. Then set up a soft link from this directory back to your normal user directory. IntelliJ should then read the same set of files whether or not you are using sudo.

eg ln -s /home/matt/.IntellijIdea13 /home/root/.IntelliJIdea13

I haven't got IntelliJ installed on Linux so can't check this.